# Android ItemizedOverlay draw method question

Tags: android, google-maps, draw, itemizedoverlay

Does anybody know the relationship between the members of an Android Itemized Overlay list and when draw() is called.  Specifically, I'm trying to find out if draw is called once for each Overlay or once only for the whole set.

Thanks,
R.

Answer (score 0):

I overrode draw() in my ProjectOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay class and in it I loop though the population of the overlay list like so:

```
 for (int ctr = 0; ctr < overlayList.size(); ctr++)
```

I haven't tested other ways of drawing the screen, because this seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, draw() is called once each time the map moves (when you touch the screen and move your finger). By once, I mean that if you want to draw text on each overlay (a name or something) you must loop through your ArrayList in your overriden draw().

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it's called twice for each visible item. However, I haven't been able to find out which item it's being called for, thus making any recalculation of drawable items difficult (to say the least)